# i am unable to insert or paste the images from desktop location to outlook mail body

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

i am trying to insert the images from desktop in outlook mail body through 
 powershell script, with below script mail is going but images not coming in 
 mail body. please check and tell me where i am doing wrong. please note I 
 dont want images as attachment i want it in mail body.please help it will 
 really very appreciable.
  Below is the powershell script

```
    $file1 = "C:\Users\rony\Desktop\screenshot.png"
    sleep 02
    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $Mail.To = "rony7@gmail.com"
    $Mail.Subject = "screenshot status"
    $Mail.HTMLBody =  @"
    <html>
    <body>
       Hi ,
    <p>Please find the below screenshots of status.
       <p>
       <img src="cid:image1.png">

       <p>Thank you!

       </body>
       </html>
    "@
    $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($file1)
    $attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = $True
    $attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = "Inline"
    $attachment.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png"
    $attachment.ContentId = 'image1.png'
    $Mail.Attachments.Add($attachment)
    sleep 05
    $Mail.Send()
```

Comment: have a look at this blog post http://winsysadm.net/send-mail-with-inline-embedded-images-with-powershell/

Comment: hi i had already checked and created the above script but not images not reflecting in mail body. please check the above script once and let me know the mistake i am doing.

Comment: which outlook version are you using?

Comment: outlook version is 2013